# single line Calculate a sum and print multiple columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe written like below

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=1, names=['all','my','headers','named'])
```

from this point, how can i apply the following forumla df['my'] - df['all'] / df['headers'] and print the name from the data below, on a single line?

example data:

```
all      my     headers    named
10.1     50.2   10         top
20.2     40.2   4          bottom
```

current attempts:

```
print(df['named'] + " " + str(  (df['my'].astype(float) - df['all'].astype(float))  /  df['headers'].astype(float)  )
```

I am trying hard to do this in one single print statement with no additional variables or lines other than the single print statement provided.

expected output:

```
top    1.01
bottom 5.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `df.apply` will work here.

```
df['answer'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['my'] - (x['all']/x['headers']), 1)
for index, row in df.itterrows: print(row['name'] + " - " + row['answer'])
```

Not a one liner, but might give you an idea of how to utilize df.apply.

Answer (score 1):

Using `astype` in `pandas`

```
print(df['named'] + " " + ((df['my'].astype(float) - df['all'].astype(float))/df['headers'].astype(float)).astype(str))
0                    top 4.01
1    bottom 5.000000000000001
dtype: object
```